# Problems with finding and replacing

Tags: regex, xml, regular-language

Hey stackoverflow community. Ive need help with huge information file. Is it possible with regular expression to find in this tag:

```
<category_name><![CDATA[Prekiniai ženklai&gt;Adler|Kita buitinė technika&gt;Buičiai naudingi prietaisai|Kita buitinė technika&gt;Lygintuvai]]></category_name>
```

Somehow replace all the other data and leave only 'Adler' or 'Lygintuvai'. Im using Altova to edit xml files, so i cant find other way then find-replace. And im new in the regex stuff. So i thought maby you can help me.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. https://regex101.com/ is a great place to learn these things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@\<category_name\>.+?gt\;([\w]+?)\|.+?gt;([\w]+?)\]\]\>\<\/category_name\>@i
\1 - Adler
\2 - Lygintuvai
```

[PHP](http://ideone.com/cXipD0)

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tD4vR0/1)

Fields may contain alphanumeric characters without spaces.

If you want to modify the scope of acceptable characters change [\w] to something other:
[a-z] - only letters
[0-9] - only digits
etc.

Comment: How can i fix this, that find replace understands \w as the letter w or W. Not the any word

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php
\w - means any "word" character.
You should try [0-9a-z] if \w doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but use of regular expressions to process XML will never be 100% correct (you can prove that using computer science theory), and it may also be very inefficient. For example, the solution given by Luk is incorrect because it doesn't allow whitespace in places where XML allows it. Much better to use XQuery or XSLT, both of which are designed for the job (and both work in Altova). You can then use XPath expressions to locate the element or attribute nodes you are interested in, and you can still use regular expressions (e.g. in the XPath replace() function) to process the content of text or attribute nodes.

Incidentally, your input is rather strange because it uses escape sequences like `&gt;` within a CDATA section; but XML escape sequences are not recognized in a CDATA section.